# blockUI trying to implent Your request is being processed pop up doesnt work on server only in debug

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to show a message and gif every time a page post method is taking a little while to process. I want this to happen on every form in the app not just one.

Therefore I have put the the following Javascript file processing.js into my scripts folder

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var submitprocessingmsg = "<strong>Processing</strong><br /><img src='~/Images/processing.gif' />";
    // Block UI when submitting forms
    $("input:submit").click(function() {
        if ($("form").valid()) {
        $.blockUI({
            message: submitprocessingmsg
        });
        }
    });
});
```

And I call it in the _Layout.cshtml page using this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Processing.js")
```

An example of the page I'm trying to fire it on is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-horizontal">
      //Various form inputs here  
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">

            <input type="submit" value="Accept Terms and Enter Event" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I have it working in debug mode, but when I deploy it to the server it doesnt work, not even an error message

Answer (score 1):

It's not firing because `input:submit` isn't an event. You'd need `form:submit`.

Comment: still not firing with that either I'm afraid

Comment: @PhillSanders, please edit your question and include more context; it would be a lot less like shooting in the dark. Like include the markup you want it to fire around.

Comment: @PhillSanders, can you also confirm it's **not firing** or that it's **not popping up**? Add a `console.log` right after that statement to see if it's firing.

Comment: @PhillSanders, can you include the Razor or markup that this button is a part of?

Comment: javascript console isnt showing the log line i put in the script

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks like jquery does have `:submit`, in their documentation they recommend using `input[type="submit"]`

I'm not sure about the `.blockUI` portion. Instead, would simply hiding the button and showing the spinner in your case work? If the page is going to postback and refresh anyway it might be just fine to do something like

https://jsfiddle.net/syu00jxt/1/